# Why ScriptBlock in PowerShell delays output until the ScriptBlock completes?

Tags: .net, powershell

I have this code:

```
Function-Step "Long operation" { MyLongRunningFunction }

function Function-Step
{
    param([string]$message,[ScriptBlock]$block)     
    Write-Host $message
    Read-Host
    $block.Invoke()
}
```

`MyLongRunningFunction` writes information to the standard output as it runs, but it doesn't show in the console until the function finishes, suddenly.

It seems that it's eating all the output of `MyLongRunningFunction` ends, and after that, it throws all the output at the same time.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Use Jobs?  That's the most straightforward way.

Comment: Use @PetSerAl Answer. That will keep the handle with the function itself.